# Inserting formula with target.column issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am running into issues getting a formula to go into the cell next to the selected cell.
I keep running into application-defined or object-defined errors

Here is the code I am having trouble with

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Column = 2 Then            
        Sheets("Scan").Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "=(INDEX(Roster!C,MATCH(Scan!RC1,Roster!C4,0))"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: in your formula are C,RC1,C4 R1C1 format or are they supposed to be the actual cell address?

Comment: @ScottCraner R1C1 format, but when I try the following code I get the same error:
               `Cells(Target.Row, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=(INDEX(Roster!C,MATCH(Scan!RC1,Roster!C4,0))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With it changing only one cell and the formula using cells from other sheets.  To make it work the formula should be in A1 format.

Also you need to denote that it is a formula with the `.Formula`

Third, there was a missing close parenthesis.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Sheets("Scan").Cells(Target.Row, 3).Formula = "=(INDEX(Roster!D" & Target.Row & ",MATCH(Scan!D" & Target.Row & ",Roster!G" & Target.Row & ",0)))"
        End If
End Sub
```

The cell address is based on your R1C1.  I may have the columns wrong double check.